# maps on quotients.

Tags: geometry, algebraic-topology, quotient-spaces, klein-bottle, non-orientable-surfaces

I'm trying to define a map over a Klein bottle $\mathbb{K}^2$ but I'm not totally sure on how to do it the right way. My approach is to define over a fundamental domain (a square) and try extending it to the quotient.
The thing is anywhere I look to get further insight about how to do it, all I can find is graph theory for maps on non-orientable surfaces.
So my questions are the following:

1. Can anyone recommend good literature about a geometrical approach to endomorphisms on quotient surfaces?
2. In any case, what should I pay attention to in order to obtain a well defined endomorphism?

In order to provide a clearer picture of what I'm trying to do, consider a fundamental a fundamental domain of the klein bottle (let's call it a ''Mobius cylinder'' for a moment to get some perspective), so we have a middle points segment parallel to the sides with identical orientations, which makes it $S^1$ once I pass to the quotient. Let's say I want to define a map over all of $\mathbb{K}^2$ that restricted to that circle is $z^2$, I don't think I will be having any trouble with that passing to the quotient, but again, since it is my first time trying maps on non orientable surfaces I don't want to make any mistakes and hasn't been easy to find any good sources. So, thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever we have a quotient object $X/\!\sim$, we will have the following [universal property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_property):

> $f : X/\!\sim \to Y$ is a map if and only if $f \circ p : X \to Y$ is a map

here $p : X \to X/\!\sim$ is the projection map.

In the setting of topological spaces, this means that maps $f : X/\!\sim \to Y$ correspond exactly to maps $\tilde{f} : X \to Y$ with the bonus property that if
$x_1 \sim x_2$ then $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$.

---

Let's now apply this to your example. We want to understand all maps from $K$ to $K$, where the Klein Bottle $K$ is defined as

$$ [0,1] \times [0,1] \bigg/ \big \{(a,0)=(a,1), (0,b)=(1,1-b) \big \} $$

By the above universal property, these correspond exactly to maps $f : [0,1] \times [0,1] \to K$ so that $f(a,0) = f(a,1)$ and $f(0,b) = f(1,1-b)$.

This technique is extremely flexible, and gives you access to *every* possible map. I don't know of any references that explicitly discuss it, but this is probably because I haven't read many books on topology. That said, this example is used in many good [category theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_theory) references, as it was one of the motivating examples for the more general notion of quotient.

---

**Edit:** I previously used $\theta \mapsto \theta^2$ as the example map, but $z^2$ in the complex plane really corresponds to $\theta \mapsto 2\theta$ in this setting. I've updated my answer to use this map instead.

---

To give a concrete example of this technique in action, say we want to give a map $K \to K$ that restricts to $2\theta$ on the circle that you've outlined. In this case, as you have noticed, it is easier to view $K$ as a quotient of a cylinder, so let's write

$$K = S^1 \times [0,1] \bigg / (\theta,0) = (-\theta,1)$$

Then a map $f : K \to K$ so that $f([(\theta, \frac{1}{2})]) = [(2\theta, \frac{1}{2})]$ corresponds to a map $\tilde{f} : S^1 \times [0,1] \to K$ with $\tilde{f}(\theta, \frac{1}{2}) = [(2\theta, \frac{1}{2})]$ with the bonus property that $\tilde{f}(\theta,0) = \tilde{f}(-\theta,1)$. Here we have written $[(\theta,x)]$ for the class of $(\theta,x)$ after quotienting.

But how do we map *into* $K$? Well if we map into $S^1 \times [0,1]$ then we can compose with the projection map $p : S^1 \times [0,1] \to K$!

So, to build our desired map $K \to K$, we follow this procedure:

> 1. Build a map $\tilde{f} : S^1 \times [0,1] \to S^1 \times [0,1]$ so that
>
>    - $\tilde{f}(\theta, \frac{1}{2}) = (2\theta, \frac{1}{2})$
>    - $\tilde{f}(\theta, 0) = \tilde{f}(-\theta, 1)$
> 2. Say the magic words "universal property of quotients!", which guarantees that this $\tilde{f}$ induces a function $f : K \to S^1 \times [0,1]$.
> 3. Finally, look at the composition $p \circ f : K \to K$, and realize it does what we want.

But this is comparatively easy! If we can find a way to do $2\theta$ at every level, in a way that reverses orientation along the way, then we'll win. We can do this by linearly interpolating between the coefficients $1$ and $-1$ in a way that depends on $x$:

$$
\tilde{f}(\theta,x) = 
\begin{cases}
((4x-1)2\theta,x) & 0 \leq x \leq \frac{1}{2}\\
(2\theta,x)       & \frac{1}{2} \leq x \leq 1
\end{cases}
$$

To be extremely explicit, the universal property says that

$$f([(\theta,x)]) = \tilde{f}(\theta,x)$$

is well defined.

Then composing with $p$ gives

$$(p \circ f)([(\theta,x)]) = p(\tilde{f}(\theta,x)) = [\tilde{f}(\theta,x)]$$

which is the desired function from $K \to K$.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: This really is! Your thorough explanation of the example is indeed nice. With the clarification stated first about how to define it via the projection map is actually all I was hoping to hear! Again, thank you very much for taking time to be so thorought! Regards!!!

Comment: I'm glad to hear it was helpful ^_^

Comment: I have been thinking a bit more about this construction, and I come to this: does every map on the 2-torus which coincides on its two respective edges descend to the klein bottle? I mean, since it is a double sheet cover, it suffices for a map to coincide in two edges to pass to the cylinder and then coincide on the other edge to pass to the torus. Taking then $x=1/2$ one can define a map on $\mathbb{K}$ to be ''half'' of the previous map on each sheet of the covering and doesn't really have to care much about the quotient because of how it was defined (exactly to make it ...)

Comment: (satisfy the condition for it to descend to the quotient). Is this simple idea right? This would be a great way to define maps on $\mathbb{K}$ in a very simple straightforward way every time!

Comment: Maybe a twisting might be required in order for this to work, I think that even when looks good already on the covering space, it could have some problems since I believe it would also have to agree on the circle in the middle, right?

Comment: Moreover, I don't either think your example works since the action of $z^2$ on $(1, \theta)$ is $(1,2\theta)$, not $(1,\theta^2)$. I got carried away the other day since your answer about how to go down to the quotient was what I wanted to hear. Also (I thought about not to mention this since it wasn't important but now that I'm on it I'll just do) but when I said ''the circle by the middle points parallel to the sides with the same orientation'' I meant the other circle. :)

Comment: I'm busy right now, but I'll read your comments later today, and edit my answer if necessary

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying with regards to the 2-torus's "respective edges", particularly with regards to twisting. Would you mind clarifying? As for the mistake you found, nice catch. That was careless of me, and I've edited the example to be $\theta \mapsto 2\theta$.

Comment: Ok, thanks for taking your time with my requests :) (specially since you're the only one who is helping me out!). My picture is this: Imagine you have a cylinder, and a map defined on it that agrees on both its ends. Then, you can ''twist'' the, say upper, end to force it descend to the quotient that gives $\mathbb{K}^2$, this should be not a problem since a twist is a homeomorphism so any topological property one may have for the original map will be inherited by the map on the twisted domain, hence being a map on $\mathbb{K}^2$ with certain desired topological property. Sounds good, right?

Comment: Remember reversing orientation is a _reflection_ not a twist. So if your map takes the same value on the boundary circles of the cylinder, no amount of twisting will let you descend to the Klein bottle (except in special cases where $f(\theta+\text{twist}) = -f(\theta)$ for some value of twist).

Comment: ok, I think I got you now. I'll let you know if I succeed. Thanks once again!